# ¿Por que me manda el siguiente mensaje al cargar una grafica Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string-Google Chart?

Tags: javascript, html, array, google-chart-api

Buen dia comáñeros , estoy implementando unos graficos en mi sitio y me enconte con google chart estoy intentando añadir dinámicamente llenar el arreglo , pero al momento de mostrar la grafica me muestra el siguiente mensaje: 
**Data column(s) for axis #0 cannot be of type string**
ya intente convertir la parte que  no es string a int pero aun asi me sigue marcando lo mismo, me podrian apoyar?
saludos.

este es mi script

```js
var chartsdata=2;
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
//["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
var data=[];
 var Header= ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }];
 data.push(Header);
 for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
      var temp=[];
      temp.push("prueba");
      temp.push(parseInt("23"));
            temp.push("#b87333");
      data.push(temp);
      
  }
  //alert(data);
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error que tienes es que en realidad nunca esta entrando al ciclo que crea la data por lo que nunca agrega ningún valor aquí mira:

```
for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata.length; i++) {
     var temp=[];
     temp.push("prueba");
     temp.push(parseInt("23"));
     temp.push("#b87333");
     data.push(temp);
}
```

No entra por la condición `chartsdata.length` que en realidad la tienes definida como una variable que almacena un número: `var chartsdata=2;`

Si lo modificas de la siguiente manera debería de funcionar

```
for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata; i++) {
     var temp=[];
     temp.push("prueba");
     temp.push(parseInt("23"));
     temp.push("#b87333");
     data.push(temp);
}
```

```js
var chartsdata=2;
google.charts.load("current", {packages:['corechart']});
    google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
    function drawChart() {
//["Gold", 19.30, "gold"],
var data=[];
 var Header= ['Element', 'Density', { role: 'style' }];
 data.push(Header);
 for (var i = 0; i < chartsdata; i++) {
      var temp=[];
      temp.push("prueba");
      temp.push(parseInt("23"));
            temp.push("#b87333");
      data.push(temp);
      
  }
  //alert(data);
  var data = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data);
      var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);
      view.setColumns([0, 1,
                       { calc: "stringify",
                         sourceColumn: 1,
                         type: "string",
                         role: "annotation" },
                       2]);

      var options = {
        title: "Density of Precious Metals, in g/cm^3",
        width: 600,
        height: 400,
        bar: {groupWidth: "95%"},
        legend: { position: "none" },
      };
      var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("columnchart_values"));
      chart.draw(view, options);
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<div id="columnchart_values" style="width: 900px; height: 300px;"></div>
```